# How do I get the required version of libpython3.8.so.1.0?

Tags: python, elementary-os

I tried to install the `deemix-pyweb` package which you can find at/I've downloaded at [download.deemix.app](https://download.deemix.app)

To do so I first extracted the downloaded zip archive from the link given before to the following directory : `home/paul/Téléchargements/Deemix/` and opened the folder in the Terminal.

Once the Terminal was opened, I entered `./deemix-pyweb`, thinking that it would launch the app. But it gave the following error :
`` [21051] Error loading Python lib '/home/paul/Téléchargements/Deemix/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/paul/Téléchargements/Deemix/libpython3.8.so.1.0) ``

I checked Python version and it is already in the latest version.
I also checked other forums but none found a solution...

For you to know, I am on *Elementary OS* which is an Ubuntu-based distribution.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: The file [android.python.3.8.3.zip](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srplab/starcore_for_android/master/android.python.3.8.3.zip) contains `libpython3.8.so`. I'm not sure of the significance of the `.1.0` - perhaps `libpython3.8.so` could be renamed to `libpython3.8.so.1.0`. Make sure you use the one matching your architecture, probably `x86_64`.